# System.Diagnostics.Process gives The system cannot find the file specified error on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Im trying to create key with keytool inside my asp.net program.

this is my code :

```
    private static bool RunCommand(string command, string working_dir, bool show_window = true)
    {
        using (System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process
        {
            StartInfo =
                      {
                        UseShellExecute = false,
                        FileName = "keytool",
                        Arguments = command,
                        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                        WorkingDirectory = working_dir
                      }
        })
        {

            proc.OutputDataReceived += Proc_OutputDataReceived; ;
            proc.Start();
            proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
            proc.WaitForExit();
            int ExitCode = proc.ExitCode;
            if (ExitCode != 0)
            {
                throw new Exception("error happend");
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

this code works fine inside Visual studio and Local IIS inside windows 10.

but when i publish it to production server it gives me :
**"The system cannot find the file specified"**

both os (local windows 10 / server 2019 ) have same openjdk 21.

both IIS have localSytem apppool permission.

this is production environment variable :

[image]

Comment: Is the directory where `keytool` is located in the path on both machines? What happens if you use an absolute path?

Comment: @RetiredNinja yes and if i type in keytool in cmd both os shows the program correctly

Comment: And you're logged in as the same user the program is run with on the production server?

Comment: Is it in the users path variable? It needs to be a systems path variable since IIS presumably run as a "special" user on your production system.

Comment: @ralf both os have same setting for environemt variables , ive update my question with image of path.

Comment: Restarted the system/IIS ? Just a guess don't know if IIS is one of those processes that needs that to notice changes to in the environment.

Comment: @ralf ah god bless you. that was the trick. the server needs to be restarted.